# What is the name of the website which rates games based on how ethical / predatory / addicting they are?

Tags: web

I'm not sure if this is the right category since it's not a programming question. If this is wrong please can someone tell me which Stackexchange would be the correct one?

My question is the following: Some time ago I had found a website which rates games based on how ethical / predatory etc games are. There were a lot of interesting categories. Games with a bad score had a lot of psychological tactics to make it addicting or make you spend money. and a good score were more ethical games. I just can't find the site again, does anyone know it? It looked like it was a pretty well known site with lots of rated games. That's why I'm wondering why it's so hard to find again. It would be great if someone can help! thanks!
Kevin

Comment: I don't think there is an StackExchange site for this kind of question. I'm also unaware of a subreddit dedicated to finding websites, but you can try https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/ - *There are plenty of review websites, but I can't think of an exact match to your description.*

Comment: thanks for the reddit link, I'll try it there!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with game development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! Stumbled over the tern "dark pattern" in a random user experience StackExchange post and that's the word I needed. [darkpattern.games](https://www.darkpattern.games/) is the website

Comment: While that itself is the answer, you could improve the answer by a lot if you would summarize the dark patterns. Who knows how long the website is available and a small summary can never hurt